# Why will this hide/show div js only work in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide, jsfiddle

I have a hide/show div script that works how I want it to here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/3537/

However when i'm coding it in anywhere else, whether I link javascript and css or embed it (as below) within the html file, it won't work.

```
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
ul.buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 18px;
    left: 43px;
    z-index: 40;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.buttons li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;


}

ul#divMenu {
height: 40px;
background-color: #ddd;
position: fixed;
padding-left: 76px;
padding-right: 15px;
bottom: 15px;
    left: 17px;
    right: 17px;
z-index: 3;
line-height: 39px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#divMenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    font-family: ProximaNovaLtRegular;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 2em;
}


#divInfo {
height: 40px;
background-color: #ddd;
position: fixed;
padding-left: 76px;
padding-right: 15px;
bottom: 15px;
    left: 17px;
    right: 17px;
z-index: 3;
line-height: 39px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.show').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});

$('.hide').click(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();

});
</script>




</head>

<body><ul class="buttons">
    <li><img src="menu.png" class="show" target="Menu"></a></li>
    <li><img src="info.png" class="show" target="Info"></a></li>
    <li><img src="close.png" class="hide" ></a></li>
</ul>


<ul id="divMenu" class="targetDiv">
                <li><a href="print.html">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="print.html#four">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="identity.html#sixteen">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="print.html#seven">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="identity.html">5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="divInfo" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try wrapping it with `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` jsFiddle runs the code onLoad in the example you provided.. Also, make sure you're including jQuery before the script..

Comment: I really recommend to read the jQuery tutorial because it tells you *exactly* what to do to get started with jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: @FelixKling it may be a duplicate but the answer here is much clearer than the answer to that question. Answers that are not really clear should not be used as a duplicate reference. IMO.

Comment: @NeilLunn: You can always improve the other answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What JSFiddle Is Doing**

*onLoad*

JSFiddle wraps any code in the JavaScript/jQuery box in `$(window).load(function(){...});`.  This is because you have the second drop down in Frameworks & Extensions set to onLoad.  With this setting, the script will wait for all media and data to load and the page to be rendered.

*onDomReady*

If you the onDomReady option, JSFiddle uses `$(function(){...});` Which just waits for the DOM to load, not necessarily all the data.

**What You Can Do**

To make you code behave as the JSFiddle code does, you can use either of the above functions.

Another common way to write similar code is `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.  like the onDomReady code, this only waits for the DOM to load.  In my opinion, this is the most commonly used method because it is the most intuitive.

Comment: `$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});` I like this form of load. Less characters to download and easy to write

Comment: True, but this only waits for the DOM (see edit).  If you need all the media and other data to load first, you need `$(window).load(function(){...});`.  There is a subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including jQuery?

If you are, make sure the DOM is loaded first.

```
$(function(){});
```